# EmberJS: Pass data between routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What do you recommend to pass a message between routes? What I would like to get is:

- Sign up page where you can register yourself in the application.
- If the register process is ok, the application will redirect you to the login page, but it should display a message with the signup response.
  I mean, if you reach the login page from the signup page redirection, it should display the signup message. If you reach the page directly, it should not display anything.

I have thought on creating a new path for the login route (signup_confirmation). There, if the path is signup_confirmation, it will display the message.

Thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286750/passing-parameters-between-routes-in-ember-2-x) and [this discussion](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-pass-parameters-between-different-routes-in-ember-2-x/12095).

Comment: Thank you! @ykaragol. Finally, I only had to pass a variable so I used query params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options:

1. Add `signupMessage` property to `login` controller, then in `signup` controller [inject](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_ad-hoc-injections) `login` controller and set a value of `signupMessage` after registration. Then you can display it in `login` template (don't forgret to clear this property when user goes away from `login` route, `deactivate` event of route should help with this).
2. Create a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/services/), `memoryStorage` to store data that can be accessed from different places. In `signup` controller you can then set a message and from `login` controller get it and display (and remove from `memoryStorage`, of course).
3. Use flash messages, which will be displayed for few seconds somewhere on the page, no matter what route is active now. [ember-cli-flash](https://github.com/poteto/ember-cli-flash) is a good addon for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Base on your requirement, the service is a great place to share data between different app state.

> An Ember.Service is an Ember object that lives for the duration of the application, and can be made available in different parts of your application.

Services are useful for features that require shared state or persistent connections. Example uses of services might include:

- User/session authentication.
- Geolocation.
- WebSockets.
- Server-sent events or notifications.
- Server-backed API calls that may not fit Ember Data.
- Third-party APIs.
- Logging.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/services/